# Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature TypeScript error

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, word-cloud

I can not solve the problem of type compatibility. Problem is there:

```
this.options.list.push(...this.cloudData.map((e: Words) => [e.word, e.size] as[string, number]) as[string, number][]);

options: Options = {
  list: [] as ListEntry
};
```

where `ListEntry` is:

```
type ListEntry = [string, number];
```

And Error is:

```
error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((...items: any[]) => number) | ((...items: [string, number][]) => number)' has no compatible call signatures.
```

Any ideas?

---

**EDIT**

`Words` type:

```
export class Words {
  word: string;
  size: number;
}
```

Comment: It might be because `options.list` is expecting a string as its first entry but you're giving it an array.

Comment: Can you please add the type `Words`?

Comment: Is added now, sorry

Comment: What is the Options type. Your code mostly works for me the only issue is that list field should be `list: [] as ListEntry[]` http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20ListEntry%20%3D%20%5Bstring%2C%20number%5D%3B%0D%0Alet%20options%20%3D%20%7B%20list%3A%20%5B%5D%20as%20ListEntry%5B%5D%20%7D%3B%0D%0Aexport%20class%20Words%20%7B%20word%3A%20string%3B%20size%3A%20number%3B%20%7D%0D%0Athis.options.list.push(...%5B%5D.map((e%3A%20Words)%20%3D%3E%20%5Be.word%2C%20e.size%5D%20as%20%5Bstring%2C%20number%5D))%3B

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir thanks its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved in comments, add so this does not remain unanswered:

Your initialization of `list` is off. Form your usage `list` should be an array of `ListEntry`

```
let options = {
  list: [] as ListEntry[]
};
```